# SSRS- how SUM function ignore negative values

Tags: reporting-services, sum, report, aggregate

i want to add only positive values in a aggregate function, i.e. sum. it should only add positive value. what i am doing is

> **SUM(((Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value)/(Fields!RemaningDays.Value+1)))**

but now i want to ignore the negative values to add.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the numerator to an `IIf` expression that will return 0 if the existing value is negative, i.e. change

```
Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value
```

to something like:

```
IIf(Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value > 0
  , Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value
  , 0)
```

Depending on the underlying data types, you may need a cast to prevent an aggregation of different data types in the expression and hence `#Error` being displayed in the report, i.e.

```
IIf(Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value > 0
  , Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value
  , CDbl(0))
```

or

```
IIf(Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value > 0
  , Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value
  , CDec(0))
```

So the whole expression will be like:

```
SUM(((IIf(Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value > 0
      , Fields!MonthlyTarget.Value-Fields!MonthToDateUnits.Value-Fields!DUSales.Value
      , 0))/(Fields!RemaningDays.Value+1)))
```